# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'SetReturnValue': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, flash, wordpress, internet-explorer

I have a page that works perfectly in all other browsers but breaks in IE.  The error from the debugger is:

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'SetReturnValue': object is null or undefined

It happens when I click a button in a flash object to call a function.  None of the buttons in the flash file work in IE but all work flawlessly in the other browsers.  Anyone have any ideas?  I've googled and really couldn't figure it out from the answers out there.

The web address is http://capitolomaha.com/reservations/

Any help is much appreciated, this is confusing me so bad.

Comment: Where does the error come from? JavaScript, Flash, IE, Wordpress? Please be more specific. Did you create the Flash file yourself?

Comment: "I have a page that works perfectly in all other browsers but breaks in IE" - how many times have I said that phrase...

Comment: Are you using FusionCharts or some simillar third party library? I had same issue with FusionCharts.

Answer (score 6):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622942%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Basically, IE9 breaks flash ExternalInterface calls if your flash component is embedded with an object tag with an embed tag fallback, and the object id and embed name is the same.

The easiest workaround is to tell ie9 to render your page in IE8 Standards mode.
To do this, insert this in the  element:

```
<!-- Enable IE8 Standards mode -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

Otherwise, you might just want to use the object tag only or embed tag only.

Comment: I know this is a little old, but automatic downvote for recommending telling IE9 to render as IE8.  Fix the object code instead

Answer (score 4):

Much of the time, this can be caused because of an embedded object swf video player (for example: JW Player etc.)

Internet Explorer seems to require two attributes for the **OBJECT** tag, namely **classid** AND **id**

For a SWF player use:

```
classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"

id="dummy"
```

NB - in principle, id can be any (non-taken) dummy string

Other good sources on how to embed video:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_object.asp

http://www.2webvideo.com/blog/embed-swf-flv-mp4-videos-in-webpage

Comment: It's perhaps years late, but the current incarnation of JWPlayer does not have an embed tag, and it does have both a classID and ID value on the object tag.  yet, in IE9, JWPlayer6.11 still throws this error at some point during (it would appear) the "remove()" routine.  I don't know whether to blame IE or JWPlayer, but I need to be able to blame somebody.  (-;

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you specify the id tag (it must have the same value as the name tag).
Although [Adobe writes](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html) that `id` is an optional tag, Internet Explorer needs the id to address the swf object with the javascript-flash interface.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I've solve it by changing the way I've included the flash.
Fristly I had

```
<object>
<embed></embed></object>
</object>
```

Than i moved to:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="780" height="420">
        <param name="movie" value="myContent.swf" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="myContent.swf" width="780" height="420">
        <!--<![endif]-->
          <p>Alternative content</p>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
      </object>
```

and with the last one it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try to verify if the element is null like below:

```
if(element == null)return false
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a JavaScript error when you click on a button in flash.  The button calls a javascript function to reveal a booking source to make a reservation for that particular table.  It's frustrating me big time.

The issue only happens in IE, nothing else, but when I debug it's a javascript error as far as I can tell.