# Respond Proxy Js

Tags: javascript

for ie7-8 I'm using respond.proxy.js along with foundation but getting an,

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'href': object is null or undifined

respond.proxy.js, line 4 character 3

```
proxyURL = doc.getElementById("respond-proxy").href
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you're asking for
[SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'SetReturnValue': object is null or undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523509/script5007-unable-to-get-value-of-the-property-setreturnvalue-object-is-null)

and this for more info

[SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'indexOf': object is null or undefined in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787799/script5007-unable-to-get-value-of-the-property-indexof-object-is-null-or-und)